# Changing the text on a label in different languages

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

Not really that easy question here.   :)

A customer has a field *ownerid* that is used as the lookup to a salesperson. I've changed the text of the label from *Owner* to *Hazaa* and I can see it take effect.

The problem is that *Hazaa* only displays in the English version (the base language of the installtion), while the language that is used for the users is Swedish. The users with Swedish language selected see the default translation, while they'd like to see *Hazaa* instead.

How can this be done?!

I could, perhaps, play around with exporting the language for translation, editing it and, then, importing back. However, that's a little, tiny, wimsy bit overkill for changing a single label. However, I suspect that only a few entities will require hazaa-fication of the *ownerid* field, while the rest is supposed to be left as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supported way to translate the label is using the translation process (an example can be found [here](http://www.magnetismsolutions.co.nz/blog/roshan/11-11-28/Modifying_Translations_in_Dynamics_CRM_2011.aspx))

Maybe you can consider to create an unmanaged solution that contains only that entity, in order to export only the necessary labels.

There is also a tool recently released by Tanguy Touzard in his toolbox, I didn't use it yet, but you can find more information here:

http://mscrmtools.blogspot.com/2013/08/new-xrmtoolbox-plugin-easy-translator.html

Comment: Hmm... I'm required to get it to work on CRM 4.0 (and 2011/2013), so solution is a no-go. I forgot to stress it. Sorry.  :)

Comment: If I remember right with CRM 4.0 you need to export all the translations and import back, but the process is the same (manually editing the xml file)